# Regular expression Skip message to,from patterns

Tags: php, regex

I have this string in php i want to skip the ppattern

```
------------------------------------------
FROM:Andy;
SENT:Mon, Jun 18 2012 1:52pm
TO:Ali;

------------------------------------------
FROM:Ali;
SENT:Mon, Jun 18 2012 12:26pm
TO:Andy;

Some message text here
```

I want to use regular expression to skip first two patterns and return only "Some message text..." there can be more of above two pattern. In PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.*TO:.*;\s*(.*)
```

Be sure to set dot matches newline

In php (preg) this becomes

```
if (preg_match('/.*TO:.*;\s*(.*)/s', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: @user1215106 Right, I updated the answer. Replace was overkill :)

Answer (score 1):

To be 100% sure you are okay, use pattern `/^.*\nSENT:[^\n]*\nTO:[^\n]*\n\n(.*)$/is`

See and test the code [here](http://ideone.com/CZywd).

---

In case you migh have some whitespace characters in empty line after last "TO:" line, then use regex `/^.*\nSENT:[^\n]*\nTO:[^\n]*\n\s*\n(.*)$/is`